# jQuery UI dialog resize

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-dialog

Used latest jQuery 1.11.2 and 2.1.3, UI 1.11.3 ( Bootstrap 3.3.2 ).
Very simple code:

```
<div id="abd">
  111
  <input style="width: 100%;">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(
 function(){
  $('#abd').dialog();
 }
);</script>
```

Certanly, it works, but after each resize action width of DIV with INPUT is decreases. If I include bootstrap.css width decreases by 34 pixel, without it by 1 pixel. Checked: FireFox, IE11. In Chrome I have extra problem - additional scrool bar in this div.

Comment: Question is: internal DIV width decreases, why?

Comment: Check jQuery 2.1.1 - same problem. After each resize operation internal width decreases. After initialization I see "width: auto;" - and view is ok, but after any resize I have "width: (nnn)px" and nnn decreases.

Comment: You input has style "width: 100%;" which means it should take whatever your widow  width is.

Comment: You can see http://mmm.pm/tmp/js/a.html Original jQuery and UI, without any modifications. width: 100% - not window width is - parent DIV. Please move up and down bottom border of dialog and width will be decreased.

Comment: Your fiddle have same problem.

Comment: What do you resize dialog window or the main window?

Comment: No browser resize. Only move up and down jQuery dialog bottom border.

Comment: Firefox : http://mmm.pm/tmp/js/fiddle2.png , print screen after 6-7 resizes. Internal width decreases.

Comment: Ok, I can  (hardly) see it. Must be a bug in the dialog onResize code.

Comment: If you include bootstrap decreases will be x34 faster! This is bug in width eval code in jQuery, UI call it. And I cann't find there is problem a lot of time.

Comment: All latest stable versions (1.x and 2.x) from download page. Last development version (not released) - I cann't find, it is difficult for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in jQuery UI with a minor priority. Two weeks ago it was not fixed, but a solution was submitted. You can read about it [here](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8932)

Comment: Tomorrow is the President Day Holiday :)

Comment: Not in my country :) Try to fix it in 2.1.3, but no so simple, code was changed. I can fix second part, but first was moved to _applyChanges and use el.width\height() functions has strange effect: I can move bottom border and width stay correct, but then I move right border internal DIV width increases :) and go out of dialog border.

Answer (score 0):

Very bad bugfix for jQuery UI 1.11.3 , tested only for UI Dialog (I use custom package only with this component).

before:

```
_applyChanges: function () {
    var props = {};

    if (this.position.top !== this.prevPosition.top) {
        props.top = this.position.top + "px";
    }
    if (this.position.left !== this.prevPosition.left) {
        props.left = this.position.left + "px";
    }
    if (this.size.width !== this.prevSize.width) {
        props.width = this.size.width + "px";
    }
    if (this.size.height !== this.prevSize.height) {
        props.height = this.size.height + "px";
    }

    this.helper.css(props);

    return props;
},
```

after:

```
_applyChanges: function () {
    var props = {};
    if (this.position.top !== this.prevPosition.top) {
        props.top = this.position.top + "px";
    }
    if (this.position.left !== this.prevPosition.left) {
        props.left = this.position.left + "px";
    }
    this.helper.css(props);
    if (this.size.width !== this.prevSize.width) {
        props.width = this.size.width + "px";
        this.helper.width(this.size.width);
    }
    if (this.size.height !== this.prevSize.height) {
        props.height = this.size.height + "px";
        this.helper.height(this.size.height);
    }
    return props;
},
```

And in resize

```
if (sum && sum >= 0) {
    style[prop] = sum || null;
}
```

changed to:

```
if (sum && sum >= 0) {
    if($.inArray(prop,['width','height'])>=0){
        el[prop](sum);
    }else{
        style[prop] = sum || null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not a solution. If bootstrap ( box-sizing: border-box; ) included it works, but without it internal div still decreases.

Answer (score 0):

A new bad fix. I can make smoothly resize in page with bootstrap and without it. 
1. remove ui plugin ("resizable", "alsoResize"); 
2. Add this to the end of _mouseDrag of "ui.resizable" widget 
P.S. So, how I write in this question title - this is only for dialogs fix.

```
$('DIV.alj-ui-dialog-content').each(function(){
    el = $(this);
    el.width(
        el.parent().width()
        - parseInt(el.css('paddingLeft'),10) - parseInt(el.css('paddingRight'),10) - 1
    );
    el.height(
        el.parent().innerHeight()
        - parseInt(el.css('paddingTop'),10) - parseInt(el.css('paddingBottom'),10)
        - $(el.parent().children('.alj-ui-dialog-titlebar')[0]).outerHeight()
        - parseInt(el.parent().css('paddingTop'),10) - parseInt(el.parent().css('paddingBottom'),10) - 3
    );
});
```